# Do i need to mud the top of horizontally mounted drywall if i am hiding the seam with quarterround?

Tags: drywall, trim

I am doing a bedroom with horizontally hung drywall. The ceiling in the bedroom is already drywall with popcorn on it. The existing wall is just wood panel with nothing behind it.

Am hoping to hide ceiling and floor lines with trim. If I hide the top edge with quarter round trim, do i need to mud the top or bottom due to the bevel edge?

Comment: I know of no code addressing this, ( *unless it is a  fire wall* )  The bottom at the floor is never taped and mudded. If you are hiding the gap at the top you may want to seal it with caulk.

Comment: I have to ask why you're going horizontal with the drywall.

Comment: @JACK Isn't horizontal the normal way? Horizontal = length side to side, Vertical = length up and down. NO?

Comment: @AlaskaMan  I would say vertical is normal. Every job I've seen has the bevelled edges going floor to ceiling.  the OP's saying he'll have to bevelled edges  going wall to wall.  i guess it depends on how even and accurately the studs are placed.

Comment: @JACK  That is very interesting.  Every job I've seen done or demolished or video i have seen  has the beveled edges going wall to wall. Meaning the tape starts at one wall and runs horizontal to the other wall. I did do a ten foot wall vertical once.

Comment: @AlaskaMan This is very strange.  Everything I've seen, watching many subdivisions being built when i was in engineering and even my own home... all vertical.

Comment: I have to say horizontal seems more common, though I’m far from an expert. A while back I saw some statistics that showed you will use less drywall if hung horizontally under most circumstances.

Comment: There was a question here a few weeks back about which way to hang it. There was considerable discussion with proponents of both directions, but it didn't come to any absolute decision.... Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: It may be regional, but it's simply _harder_ to install drywall vertically, so if you have separate crews hanging and taping, you'll get horizontal. The only place I've ever seen vertical is for garage firewalls, where seams must be backed.

Comment: I thought the main advantage of hanging drywall horizontally was a reduction in the length of joints that have to be finished.  But this may only come into play when handling 12' sheets as opposed to 8' sheets.  If you've got a wall that's 11 feet long, 8 feet high, you can finish that with 2 sheets of drywall run horizontally, with a single 11 foot seem in the center.  Covering the wall with vertical sheets would mean 2 vertical joints, 16 feet total.  This ignores top and corner joints.

Comment: Also horizontal hanging spans across studs, making a straighter surface, especially with 5/8". There's no hinge line that spans an entire plane, assuming you're staggering the panels. Same as any other sheathing. Always cross span, and staggered.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mud the top and bottom, the bevelled edge will show up. At the bottom the baseboard would be at a slight angle and could screw up your mitered angles. The bevelled edge will definitely show up at the top with only quarter round mounted up there. Mounting the quarter round up there might be harder than you think.

Comment: +1 exactly right, the bevel is *wider* than your quarter-round.

Comment: I have used shims for the bottom to get past the taper, whether it is 1/8" shims on the floor if the gap is to small at the floor or 1/2" shims if the space is big enough to slip it under the drywall edge and touch the plate.. FWIW, I have seen drywall hung horizontally in all cases in the trade for the past 47 years. But when I hang it, in most cases, I will go vertical to minimize broad joints. +1

Answer (score 0):

Without tape and mud the top joint would allow air infiltration and insect ingress. AFIK it is always done and may be the code.

What size quarter round did you have in mind? The proper molding would be some crown molding.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not *need* to. Code doesn't address that as it's purely an aesthetic issue (excepting in cases of firewalls). A zillion lake homes up here in the Great White North have pine boards for wall paneling, and there's no real seal at ceiling corners other than poly sheeting behind in modern homes.

As was mentioned, you probably want to skim to flatten the taping channel.